# Facebook Authentication Process

Tags: ruby, cookies, facebook-graph-api, sinatra

I'm currently using the Facebook Javascript API to allow users to login to my app as follows:

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
      </script>
      <fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
    </body>
 </html>
```

I am then using ruby to check the generated 'fbs_...' cookie and thus authenticate a user. From this point I'm not sure whether I should be handling my own sessions our using the created cookie to check if the user is valid - surely they should remain logged into my app whilst they are logged into facebook? And if not, how can I possibly implement a logout function?

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate the user by using the API itself

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
  } else {
    // no user session available, someone you dont know
  }
});
```

also the api provides a logout

```
FB.logout(callback);
```

FB docs are poor... But anyway read that, its the only way to get latest changes on their sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use sinatra to manage the user data and treat Facebook as a authentication provider using Omniauth.

[Ominauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) or a similar solution allows the user to stay logged into a application even if a) they log out of Facebook or b) the FB cookie disappears. The user can also log out of the application without logging out of Facebook. You can also store additional data about the user that is not from Facebook. Here is a example of [Sinatra with Omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Sinatra-Example). On the callback you would set your session cookie after a successful authentication. You could also populate the session or a User model with the information from the provider so that you retained that info.

And as a plus you also have the ability to [support more providers like](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Using-Multiple-Providers) OpenID, Google Apps or even Twitter instead of Facebook.

### Edit #1: Updated to reflect that the question was about sinatra and could not use devise

Comment: So with this strategy, once the user is authenticated their session on your app is independent of what happens on Facebook?

Comment: Also, this is a Sinatra app so I don't think I can use devise?

Comment: Correct to both comments, once they are authenticated, their session is independent. You can still use OmniAuth to authenticate with Sinatra without Devise and simply generate a session on the callback URL and either keep everything in a session or store user info attached to the session in the DB. I updated my answer with Sinatra info.